# Python qt4 - passing arguments in QtCore.QObject.connect

Tags: python, signals, qt4, slot, qt-connection

I want to react to a mouse click on a QLabel.
To achieve this I have redefined the method mouseReleaseEvent of QLabel.
I want to pass two arguments to the slot:

- the QtGui.QMouseEvent
- an ID of the clicked QLabel

But I can only pass one parameter. Either QtGui.QMouseEvent or the ID.
The combination does not work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class ExtendedQLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    
    #labelClickSignal_1 = pyqtSignal(QtGui.QMouseEvent)
    labelClickSignal_1 = pyqtSignal(QtGui.QMouseEvent, int)
    labelClickSignal_2 = pyqtSignal()
 
    def __init(self, parent):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        
    # redefinition 
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        
        #self.labelClickSignal_1.emit(event)
        self.labelClickSignal_1.emit(event, 0)
        self.labelClickSignal_2.emit()
        

class Test(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.names = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']

        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        
        row = 0
        for name in self.names:
            self.addLabel(name, row)
            row = row + 1
            
    def addLabel(self, name, row):
       
        label = ExtendedQLabel(name)
        
        # QtGui.QMouseEvent is automatically passed to the slot
        label.labelClickSignal_1.connect(self.onLabelClicked_1)
        
        # The row ID is passed to the slot
        label.labelClickSignal_2.connect(lambda id = row: 
                                 self.onLabelClicked_2(id))
                                 
        # *This does not work*
        label.labelClickSignal_1.connect(lambda id = row: 
                                 self.onLabelClicked_3(QtGui.QMouseEvent, id))
                                 
        self.grid.addWidget(label, row, 1)
       
        row = row + 1
        
    def onLabelClicked_1(self, event):
        
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print('right')
        else:
            print('left')

    def onLabelClicked_2(self, id):
        
        print('Label {0} clicked'.format(id))
        
    def onLabelClicked_3(self, event, id):

        # *This does not work*
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print('right {0}'.format(id))
        else:
            print('left {0}'.format(id))

def main():        
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    t = Test()
    t.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since your code had several pieces that did not work I rewrote the important Parts to achieve what you want. Please Note that I use PySide and not PyQt. This means you have to change the importe Statements and the `Signal` back to PyQt Notation.
The rest is explained in the code.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class ExtendedQLabel(QtGui.QLabel):

    #Signal that emits on MouseRelease
    labelClickSignal_1 = QtCore.Signal(QtGui.QMouseEvent, int)

    # init to -1
    labelId = -1

    # This is the new Constructor, Please note the double underscore 
    # before and behind `init`
    def __init__(self, parent, labelId):
        self.labelId = labelId
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)

    # emit labelClickSignal
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.labelClickSignal_1.emit(event, self.labelId)


class Test(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

       # same as yours [...]

    def addLabel(self, name, row):

        # please note the added argument
        label = ExtendedQLabel(name,row)

        # connect the signal
        label.labelClickSignal_1.connect(self.onLabelClicked_1)

        self.grid.addWidget(label, row, 1)

        row = row + 1

    def onLabelClicked_1(self, event,labelId):    
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print('right')
            print(labelId)
        else:
            print('left')
            print(labelId)
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**
You have to define your Signal to support your two arguments:

```
labelClickSignal_1 = pyqtSignal(QtGui.QMouseEvent,int)
```

See [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) for additional information.

**Example from the docs:**

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal

class Foo(QObject):

    # This defines a signal called 'closed' that takes no arguments.
    closed = pyqtSignal()

    # This defines a signal called 'rangeChanged' that takes two
    # integer arguments.
    range_changed = pyqtSignal(int, int, name='rangeChanged')

    # This defines a signal called 'valueChanged' that has two overloads,
    # one that takes an integer argument and one that takes a QString
    # argument.  Note that because we use a string to specify the type of
    # the QString argument then this code will run under Python v2 and v3.
    valueChanged = pyqtSignal([int], ['QString'])
```

Comment: I changed my code but it does not work. Maybe I did not understand your answer.

Comment: Believe it or not. This is exactly the same solution I found 10 minutes ago and wanted to post now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. Your `lambda` with the comment `*and this does not work*` took only one argument, though the slot is defined to take two. So I just skipped the first argument.

Next issue: It is difficult to pass Events that have been generated by system. I think they are destroyed after they have been handled. So I copied the data of the event into a `namedtuple` and passed this instead. (I also tried to copy the event, but this did not work somehow.)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from collections import namedtuple

class ExtendedQLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    MouseEventTuple = namedtuple('MouseEventTuple', 'type pos button buttons modifiers')
    #labelClickSignal_1 = pyqtSignal(QtGui.QMouseEvent)
    labelClickSignal_1 = pyqtSignal(MouseEventTuple, int)
    labelClickSignal_2 = pyqtSignal()

    def __init(self, parent):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)

    # redefinition 
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):

        eventTuple =  ExtendedQLabel.MouseEventTuple(type = event.type(), pos = event.pos(), button = QtCore.Qt.RightButton, buttons = event.buttons(), modifiers = event.modifiers())
        self.labelClickSignal_1.emit(eventTuple, 0)
        self.labelClickSignal_2.emit()


class Test(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.names = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']

        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)

        row = 0
        for name in self.names:
            self.addLabel(name, row)
            row = row + 1

    def addLabel(self, name, row):

        label = ExtendedQLabel(name)

        # QtGui.QMouseEvent is automatically passed to the slot
        label.labelClickSignal_1.connect(self.onLabelClicked_1)

        # The row ID is passed to the slot
        label.labelClickSignal_2.connect(lambda id = row: 
                                 self.onLabelClicked_2(id))

        # *This works now*
        label.labelClickSignal_1.connect(lambda _unused_, id = row: 
                                 self.onLabelClicked_3(QtGui.QMouseEvent, id))

        self.grid.addWidget(label, row, 1)

        row = row + 1

    def onLabelClicked_1(self, eventTuple):

        if eventTuple.button == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print('right')
        else:
            print('left')

    def onLabelClicked_2(self, id):

        print('Label {0} clicked'.format(id))

    def onLabelClicked_3(self, eventTuple, id):

        # *This does not work*
        if eventTuple.button == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print('right {0}'.format(id))
        else:
            print('left {0}'.format(id))

def main():        
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    t = Test()
    t.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I do not understand why in my code onLabelClicked_1 is working without the eventTuple. In the debugger I see a difference. In onLabelClicked_1 the event variable is an instance <PyQt4.QtGui.QMouseEvent object at 0x0000000005CD4A60>. In onLabelClicked_3 event is no instance <class 'PyQt4.QtGui.QMouseEvent'>

Comment: @pythonic Yes, it is no instance, because you provide just the class: `QtGui.QMouseEvent`. To create a instance, you have to 'call' the class: `QtGui.QMouseEvent(type, pos, button, buttons, modifiers)` with all those properties.